# Active menu class with php function

Tags: php, class

I'm not getting it done, I need to put a class on the output of the function.

Can you help, when the menu item is `active` there has to be put a class to the link.

This is the code:

```
function loadMenu()
      {
     $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM  cms_page WHERE  site_id =2  AND  page_inmenu =1 AND  page_active =1");
    if ($DEBUG)
         echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   $last_parent = $row['page_name']; 
        echo "<a href={$row['link_name']}>{$row['page_name']}</a>";

         }  
     }
```

Comment: Where's your Mysql connection? Also, i think your href is missing quotes for the link_name.

Answer (score 2):

```
function loadMenu()
{
    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM  cms_page WHERE  site_id =2  AND  page_inmenu =1 AND  page_active =1");
    if ($DEBUG)
        echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $last_parent = $row['page_name']; 
        $class = $row['active'] === true ? ' class="active"' : '';
        echo "<a href=\"{$row['link_name']}\"{$class}>{$row['page_name']}</a>";

    }   
}
```

Also your

Comment: Hi Beiller, thanks, but this one is not working for me. It ads nothing to the active link.

Comment: $row['active'] === true -- that needs to be swapped with however you determine if a link is 'active'

Comment: thats the issue where i'm trying to getting a sollution for... How can i determine when a link is active

Comment: Its impossible for me to answer that without knowing more. You could say something like $thispagename == $row['page_name']

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what's your issue.

So, if you aren't displaying anything, probably a MySQL issue.

1- Reference for Mysql (Look at OZ_'s answer) : [How to put mysql inside a php function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104335/how-to-put-mysql-inside-a-php-function)

2- As mentionned by Beiller, you'll need a way to see if the link is active.

Solution A : Might need some adjustment according $row['link_name'] value.

```
    $class = ($row['link_name'] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].)?' class="active" ' : '';
```

Solution B : Simply stick to CSS - http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm

```
    .mylink:active{ background-color:pink; }
```

3- Href needs quotes on around the URL.
also, I'm not a big fan of {} inside strings.

```
    echo "<a href=\"". $row['link_name'] ."\"". $class .">". $row['page_name'] ."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks beiller for the help..

This is the function now:

```
function loadMenu(){
     $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM  cms_page WHERE  site_id =2  AND  page_inmenu =1 AND  page_active =1");
    if ($DEBUG)
         echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   $last_parent = $row['page_name']; 
        echo "<a href={$row['link_name']}>{$row['page_name']}</a>";
}}
```

This is the call:

```
<div id="header_menu">
           <? loadMenu (); ?>
</div>
```

And mysql has the following tables:

- page_id
- page_name
- link_name
- site_id
- order_id
- page_menu
- page_inmenu
- page_leftmenu
- page_text
- page_active